# Merging Python Dictionaries and adding similar value of values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like :

```
[{'A': 2, 'B': u'cat'}, {'A': 1, 'B': u'dog'}, {'A': 3, 'B': u'rabbit'}, {'A': 4, 'B': u'cat'}, {'A': 4, 'B': u'dog'}, {'A': 8, 'B': u'rabbit'}]
```

I want to convert it into :

```
[{'cat':'6'},{'dog':'5'}, {'rabbit':'11'}]
```

I tried doing something like this :

```
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for d in ss:
            for k, v in d.iteritems():
                super_dict[k].add(v)
```

But it returns :

```
{'A': set([2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 7]), 'B': set([u'cat', u'dog', u'rabbit'])}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should show at least minimal effort to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry about that. Just added how I was doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = [{'A': 2, 'B': u'cat'}, {'A': 1, 'B': u'dog'}, {'A': 3, 'B': u'rabbit'}, {'A': 4, 'B': u'cat'}, {'A': 4, 'B': u'dog'}, {'A': 8, 'B': u'rabbit'}]
>>> new_dict = {}
>>> for item in my_list:
...     new_dict[item['B']] = new_dict.get(item['B'], 0) + item['A']
...
>>> new_dict
{u'dog': 5, u'rabbit': 11, u'cat': 6}
```